# Pandas could not convert string to float when reading from SQL database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLite database created with SQLAlchemy which has the format below

```
Code     Names              Amt1    Amt2   Amt3    Amt4
502      Real Management     11.4   1.3    -        -
5TG      80Commercial        85.8   152    4.845    4.12%
AZG      Equipment Love      11.6   117.1  -        -
```

But when I tried to read this into a pandas dataframe by using

`pandas.read_sql('sqlite_table', con=engine)`

It returns me with an error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'`

I get that pandas can't register `-` in the Dataframe, but how can I work around this? Is it possible to read it `-` as `0` or something??

Comment: have you tried `read_sql_table` instead?

Comment: Yep. I tried `read_sql_table` but it gives me the same error message

Comment: Can you try updating your `Amt3` then? remove `-` and try again

Comment: Manually. I can do it. but this spans 60000 rows..

Comment: What is your table definition, i.e. what is the type of the Atm columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update all rows in `Amt3` with `-` (if you have set up your login auths and defined cursor) will be something like this:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE sqlite_table SET Amt3 = 0 WHERE Amt3 = '-'")
```

This seems to work fine for me, even with -, what is the type of your `Atm3`?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(r"/Users/hugohonorem/Desktop/mytable.db") #create database

conn = sqlite3.connect('mytable.db') #connect to database
c = con.cursor() #set 

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE mytable
             (Code text, Names text, Atm1 integer, Atm2 integer, Atm3 integer, Atm4 integer)''')

c.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('502', 'Real Management', '11.4', '1.3', '-' , '-')")
conn.commit()
```

So we have replicated your table, we can now remove your `-`

```
c.execute("UPDATE mytable SET Atm3 = NULL WHERE Atm3 = '-'") #set it to null

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from mytable", con)
print df
```

This will give us the output:

```
  Code            Names  Atm1 Atm2  Atm3 Atm4
   502  Real Management  11.4  1.3  None    -
```

However, as you can see I can retrieve the table with `Atm4` being `-`

Comment: Is it possible to do `Atm3=-` in sqlite? And wouldn't it be more correct to use the `null` value insead.

Comment: But you should use quotes `Atm='-'` to check for strings (`text` in sqlite).

Comment: Thanks Hugo! The above statement works for me. Although, I think its better to put the `table` and the `columns` in "quotes" in case you have spaces in the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I ran into the same problem recently and this was the first result on google. What solved my problem was just to change `pandas.read_sql('sqlite_table', con=engine)` to the full query `pandas.read_sql('SELECT * FROM sqlite_table', con=engine)` as it seems to bypass the conversion attempt and it wasn't needed to edit the table.